# Refactoring from nested ifs to link_to_if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I had the following `if` statement in a shared view:

```
<% if activity.holder.user.profile_type == "Manager" %>
  DAMANAGER
<% elsif profile == "managers" %>
  <%= link_to activity.holder.name, managers_enterprise_path(activity.holder) %>
<% else %>
  <%= activity.holder.name %>
<% end %>
```

*profile is a local string variable that will be `"enterprises"` or `"managers"` depending which profile is logged in!*

activity is a local variable too from an `#each` statement

---

The view is shared between only two users with differents profiles (Enterprise and Manager), with this constraint:

- If the managers is the owner of activity it should display `DAMANAGER`
- When I'm seeing as manager unless the holder is the manager it should display a link to show the enterprise that owns this activity.
- When I'm seeing as enterprise it should display, who owns the activity, the holder name. Without links.

So I struggled myself and refactor from that to this, that's what I got by now:

```
<%= link_to_if (profile == 'managers'), activity.holder.name, managers_enterprise_path(activity.holder) %>
```

But this doesn't display `DAMANAGER` and furthermore it shows the enterprise's `id` equal to manager's `id`, since it pass the manager to `managers_enterprise_path`. The question is:

**How I can improve it?**

Thanks in advance, tell me if you need more code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a maintainable way to do it without `if ... else ... end`. The `elsif ... else ... end` part can be replaced with a `link_to_if`:

```
<% if activity.holder.user.profile_type == "Manager" %>
  DAMANAGER
<% else %>
  <%= link_to_if profile == "managers", activity.holder.name, managers_enterprise_path(activity.holder) %>
<% end %>
```